# Need a Windows batch file that will add string to each line of a dir command to produce a file list

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am working with the Informatica platform that only allows me to use batch files. I am currently producing a list of file names with the command
`dir /b /a-d`

```
850_B_4545703_.txt
850_B_003029660_.txt
850_B_069029548_.txt
850_B_188789_.txt
850_C_ENT_1712865_.txt
850_C_ENT_1712871_.txt
850_C_1712877_.txt
```

But for Informatica to use this list to locate files I have to add path used in the flat file connection which is

> \\jdeappp03\EDI\

So what I am trying to achieve is a batch file that will output the following:

```
\\jdeappp03\EDI\850_B_4545703_.txt
\\jdeappp03\EDI\850_B_003029660_.txt
\\jdeappp03\EDI\850_B_069029548_.txt
\\jdeappp03\EDI\850_B_188789_.txt
\\jdeappp03\EDI\850_C_ENT_1712865_.txt
\\jdeappp03\EDI\850_C_ENT_1712871_.txt
\\jdeappp03\EDI\850_C_1712877_.txt
```

I tried using `dir /s/b *.txt` but this give the absolute path which my setup of Informatica is not able to use to find the files.

Is there a way to get my desired result with a batch file?

Comment: does this help?  https://superuser.com/questions/1767673/how-do-you-prepend-a-string-to-each-line-of-a-file-in-ms-dos?noredirect=1#comment2751444_1767673  It might put a carriage return after which might not be ideal. And it'd have to be the same string before each line.

Comment: In PowerShell, `dir -attributes !directory | % { write-output ('\\blah\blah\' + $_.name) }` or slightly simpler if adequate `dir *.txt | % ...` or in CMD `powershell -c "{same}"`. (Powershell `dir` is actually an alias for `get-childitem` or its short form `gci`, which you can use if you wish. Similarly `%` is `foreach-object`.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You wrote "slightly simpler if adequate `dir *.txt | %`"   Doing  `dir *.txt | %` gives "'%' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @barlop I said "In Powershell" -- you're not using Powershell. Also, I said `dir *.txt | % ...` where `...` is a special written form called an elllipsis that in this case means "fill out the same (command) string from the previous example, which is long enough I didn't want to waste space and effort repeating it" -- although this explanation has now wasted more space and effort than the ellipsis saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following command in a batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d <PATH>') do (echo \\jdeappp03\EDI\%%a)
```

Using a for loop around the command allows you to iterate through its output and save it in the variable `%%a`. Everything you want to do during that iteration comes after `do`.

You only need parentheses after `do` if you want to use linebreaks for readability.

Use `for /?` in the Windows cmd to learn more about the `for` command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A shorter option would be:

```bath
for %%i in ("D:\Path\*.txt")do echo \\jdeappp03\EDI\%%~nxi
```